# Java PrimeFaces Autocomplete Facet Repeating Same Groups While Grouping

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, autocomplete

I am working on a Java EE project and using Primefaces. I try to show search operation results by group. In order to show results, I am using [primefaces autocomplete facet](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml). I reach some consequences but the problem is that same groups are repeating as you see below.('0002','000' groups repeated)

[image]

```
<p:autoComplete id="generalSearch" completeMethod="#{search.afterSearch}"  minQueryLength="3"
                                    var="doc" itemLabel="#{doc.get('NAME')}" itemValue="#{doc}" forceSelection="true" groupBy="#{doc.get('CODE')}"
                                    converter="searchConverter" scrollHeight="500"
                                    effect="blind" styleClass="SearchText" placeholder="Search"/>
```

Here is my SearchConverter class

```
@FacesConverter("searchConverter")
public class SearchConvert implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if(value != null && value.length() > 0) {
            try {
                SearchBean sBean = (SearchBean) context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("search");
                System.out.println("VALUE " + value);
                return sBean.getDocs().get(Integer.parseInt(value));
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                Log.debug("ERROR");
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid theme."));
            }
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if(value != null) {
            return (String) ((SolrDocument) value).get("id");
        }
        return null;
    }    
}
```

I am not sure `getAsObject` function whether is working or not. Because I can't see the output of `System.out.println("VALUE " + value);`

Comment: Are you sure the your list which return by method 'completeMethod="#{search.afterSearch}" doenot have the 000 002 value check-it-out.

Comment: My list has the value 000 and 0002 but why two different groups are there in list? @ankushyadav

Comment: Ohh wait primeface doesn't check the other groups just before one. @ankushyadav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh wait primeface doesn't check the other groups just before one.
So use `group by` when you execute select command